# special char in NSString

Tags: iphone

When I load the audio name, some include char "[","]"
How to convert such string include "[","]" to OBJ-C compatible string?

Welcome any comment
Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Objective-C string is defined with an @ and quotes. `@"["` works fine for me ... Maybe you could clarify your question a bit?

Answer (score 0):

To create a static `NSString`, do this:

```
NSString *stringA = @"a string with some square brackets [ ] ";
```

If you have a C string, you can create an `NSString` using the following methods (depending on whether your string is encoded in ASCII or UTF8:

```
char *utf8String;
NSString *stringB = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8String];

char *asciiString;
NSString *stringC = [NSString stringWithCString:asciiString encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```